# Matplotlib OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting three sets of roughly 20 time series. Each time series has 1.8 million points and I am plotting them separately. In order to reduce execution time (because I found out that the figure() function is quite time consuming), I open one figure only, plot and then clean it for the next time series. Something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure() # open a figure for plotting
for v in range(nfigs):
    # here I build the x and y vectors from the raw data
    # and also the figname string
    plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=0.3)
    plt.title('a title')
    plt.xlabel('x-label')
    plt.ylabel('y-label')
    plt.grid()
    plt.draw()
    plt.savefig(figname)
    plt.clf()
plt.close() # close the figure after the job is done
```

All the plots are saved ok except for one in particular in all the data sets which gives me the following error (edited the file paths for privacy):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "batch.py", line 142, in <module>
    main(fn)
  File "batch.py", line 94, in main
    plt.savefig(figname+'_'+nn+'.png')
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4agg.py", line 167, in print_figure
    FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 505, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 562, in draw
    drawFunc(renderer, gc, tpath, affine.frozen())
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 938, in _draw_lines
    self._lineFunc(renderer, gc, path, trans)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 978, in _draw_solid
    renderer.draw_path(gc, path, trans)
  File "~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 145, in draw_path
    self._renderer.draw_path(gc, path, transform, rgbFace)
OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks
```

The time series that triggers this error has absolutely nothing special about it, I have checked it with a simple show() instead of savefig(). It is neither the first one nor the last one (in roughly 60 time series) but it is enough to break my script. Help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: Plotting a million points is rather pointless. You should sample/smooth/average your data prior to plotting!

Comment: The idea is precisely to perform a visual screening of the entire raw data set in order to make decisions about the best preprocessing options. That is why my question is focused on the matplotlib error on a single time series (from an array of roughly sixty).

Comment: try not connecting the points with lines, just plot markers instead. `plot(x, y, '.')`

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell, that solved my issue (I am using '--' instead for the plot style) although it does not solve the matplotlib problem. Based on your reply, it now seems to me that matplotlib is not able to make "dense" line plots, meaning that 1.8 million points ranging from -0.05 to 0.05 in the y-axis will incur in overflow somewhere...

Comment: '--' should also draw lines so I am confused.

Comment: @tcaswell: It draws dashed lines and for some reason that does not cause an error.

Comment: 90% sure it only fixes it by chance in your case.

Comment: I am placing an issue through the Matplotlib users list.

Comment: '.' will also fail given enough points. this is an oversight by the matplotlib devs. they really shouldn't assume that everyone will or wants to sample out their data before plotting...

Comment: Just a comment, for history: I face the same question, where I have pretty long plots (~1 millions points, ~100 series). A solution I found was simply to `resample()` my `pandas.DataFrame` with `min()`, then `max()`, and plot these; then, the user would know when things happen, and may then limit the time range. Depending on the need, the plotting of some indicator of frequency/oscillations could also be interesting.

Answer (score 11):

You can try to change the value of `agg.path.chunksize` (10000-100000) in the `matplotlibrc` file or during run time in `matplotlib.rcParams`. It causes the renderer to plot paths in chunks rather than the whole path at once; but according to the docs it might cause artifacts. See the sample `matplotlibrc` file at http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/customizing.html for some more information.

Comment: I followed these instructions and I am still getting the same error. Is there any other potential solution to this problem?

Comment: given that we're talking about gigantic plots here, this isn't going to do more than delay when the error is going to show up...

Answer (score 7):

when sets`matplotlib.pyplot.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 20000`, my problem is solved. The png figure is fine.