# pyplot savefig allocating too many blocks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a figure with several million triangles, but matplotlib seems to be unable to handle it.
When I try to save the figure using `savefig('file.png', dpi=100)`, I get the following error:

```
OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks
```

And this is the entire code I use for plotting:

```
plt.figure()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.tricontourf(objpts[0], objpts[1], tris, tempdata, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.savefig('foo.png',dpi=100,bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```

Is there any way to increase the amount of allocatable blocks, or to render the plot in chunks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matplotlib OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330475/matplotlib-overflowerror-allocated-too-many-blocks)

Comment: Not a duplicate, since the fix proposed in there doesn't work.