# "OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks":

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, error-handling

Before posting this question, I checked all the possible duplicate questions and tried all the method and still could not solve the problem.

I have a simple plot in matplotlib. When I comment out the line calling `plt.fill_between()` the code works perfectly, but when I uncomment it will throw overflow error.

**Note: This error occurs in my laptop with Ubuntu 15.10

      However in MacOS I tried the same code and it shows no error (surprising!)**

**Update:** 
I used backend as TkAgg.

```
print(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
# Answer is agg.
```

My code is shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Author  : Bhishan Poudel
# Date    : Mar 28, 2016
# Topic   : OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks
# Note    : python --version ==> Python 2.7.10
# Note    : lsb_release -a   ==> ubuntu 15.10

# Imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plot values
x = np.arange(0.001, 25.0, 0.01)
A = 4.3
y = np.array( (-1.0/x) + (0.5*A*A/(x**2)) - (A*A/(x**3)) )

# Plots
plt.plot(x,y,color='k')

# Set axes limits
plt.ylim(-0.04,0.06)

# Attempt to resolve OverflowError
plt.rcParams['backend'] = 'TkAgg'  # or, 'qt4agg'
plt.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 100000
# This did not worked!

# Fill the color
plt.fill_between(x, -0.04, y, color='darkgray', alpha=.5)
# If I comment this line there will be no error!

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The links I tried are following:

[Matplotlib OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330475/matplotlib-overflowerror-allocated-too-many-blocks)
[pyplot savefig allocating too many blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229416/pyplot-savefig-allocating-too-many-blocks)
http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/customizing.html

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5907
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/matplotlibrc.template

After going through these links my initial attempt is like this:

```
# Attempt to resolve OverflowError
plt.rcParams['backend'] = 'TkAgg'  # or, 'qt4agg'
plt.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 100000
# This did not worked!
```

Attempt #2:
I created a file `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`
Then placed following code inside it:

```
agg.path.chunksize : 10000        # 0 to disable; values in the range
                                  # 10000 to 100000 can improve speed slightly
                                  # and prevent an Agg rendering failure
                                  # when plotting very large data sets,
                                  # especially if they are very gappy.
                                  # It may cause minor artifacts, though.
                                  # A value of 20000 is probably a good
                                  # starting point.
```

Attempt #3: I also installed module seaborn

```
sudo -H pip install seaborn
```

and studied some documentation.
https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial.html
However, I also couldn't find the resolution to this problem.

**Update :**
The error report is following:

```
bhishan@poudel:~/OneDrive/Programming/Python/pyprograms/plotting/matplotlib_customization$ /bin/sh /tmp/geany_run_script_R6KUEY.sh
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/collections.py:571: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if self._edgecolors == str('face'):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 338, in resizeEvent
    self.draw()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 148, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 469, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1079, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2092, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 751, in draw
    Collection.draw(self, renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 293, in draw
    mpath.Path(offsets), transOffset, tuple(facecolors[0]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 124, in draw_markers
    return self._renderer.draw_markers(*kl, **kw)
OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
```

**Update:** The required plot is as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Can you also include the traceback you get?  I can not reproduce this on current master + python 3

Comment: matplotlib uses another backend for plotting in macosx and linux, see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5907. The problem seems to be that your data file is large and if you use `fill_between` there are even more points to plot

Comment: try this to see which backend you are using `plt.get_backend()`

Comment: I can reproduce this with Python 3.4.2, Matplotlib 1.4.2. Backend is TkAgg here. Thumbs up for the research up front, btw! Some questions: I could remove the "subplots" line, do you need it? Also, just calling `plt.fill_between(x, y)` worked for me, too.

Comment: I need to fill between the curve and the bottom line (y= -0.04, not y=0.0) and this gives error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error on my computer, but if you want to change `matplotlib`'s backend, it is better to do it before importing `pyplot`.

Try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg') # I'd advise testing 'Gtk3Agg' or 'Qt4Agg' (or 5) instead
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(mpl.get_backend()) # check that the change occurred
```

**EDIT:** ok, I found the problem, it is because your function is almost diverging so `matplotlib` thinks it has a huge surface to cover... try:

```
plt.fill_between(x, -0.04, np.clip(y,-0.04,0.06))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this did not worked on Ubuntu 15.10,  i tried mpl.use('Qt5Agg') # I'd advise testing 'Gtk3Agg' or 'Qt4Agg' (or 5) instead, TkAgg
mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 100000  # THEN REST OF THE CODE. it gives the same old overflow error.

Comment: Ok, and the ``print`` indeed attests that the backend changed? Did you try without modifying ``mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize']`` with the new backend (just to be on the safe side)? Also try replacing ``color`` by ``facecolor``, since your error seems to be related to the edges...

Comment: Changing color to facecolor and none of the Agg backends works!  If you are using ubuntu, what is your ubuntu version and matplotlib version?

Comment: ok, I was able to reproduce it on another laptop with python 2.7 and matplotlib 4.4.2; see edit for a solution that worked on my machine. I'll check the difference with the other machine tomorrow.