# overflow error Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I want do stuff  with sound/ audio and music processing. 
Before this i created a sample signal with a 10 second sweep.
I have a simple script which have to plot some signals.
First signal is a simple sine; second a sweep; Both with frequency just below Nyquist frequency so thats no problem.

The Code:

```
#import
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

f0 = 50
f1 = 20000 
t1 = 10
t = np.arange(0,t1,1/44100)#[numpy.newaxis]; 
print(t.shape)

sine = np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t)

plt.plot(t, sine)
plt.xlabel('Angle [rad]')
plt.ylabel('sin(t)')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()

sweep = sig.chirp(t,f0,t1,f1,'linear',90) 

plt.plot(t, sweep)
plt.xlabel('Angle [rad]')
plt.ylabel('sin(t)')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

When I run the Python code it runs fine with the simple sine wave, but not with the sweep.

It gave the following error(s):

```
runfile('C:/Users/****/Documents/python/test_sweep.py', wdir='C:/Users/****/Documents/python')
(441000,)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 330, in __call__
return printer(obj)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 207, in <lambda>
png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 117, in print_figure
fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2158, in print_figure
**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 521, in print_png
FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 469, in draw
self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1085, in draw
func(*args)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2110, in draw
a.draw(renderer)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 715, in draw
drawFunc(renderer, gc, tpath, affine.frozen())

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 1072, in _draw_lines
self._lineFunc(renderer, gc, path, trans)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 1112, in _draw_solid
renderer.draw_path(gc, path, trans)

File "C:\Users\****\Documents\python\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 163, in draw_path
self._renderer.draw_path(gc, path, transform, rgbFace)

OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks
```

When Changing the frequency `f1` to around 10% of the sample frequency i don't have any errors.
But i wanna create some sweeps within the CD audio range so what's happent and how to avoid this problem

Edit: I use Spyder with IPython on Windows/ Ubuntu.

edit 2: I know that the screen resolution is not fine enough... but otherwise GNU octave/ matlab/ ... it work well.
the simple sinewave with the same number of samples works fine... so it the different in reaction on data points...

Comment: Your code works for me on Mac OS X and Python 3.5.

Comment: Yesterday on ubuntu and today at windows both didn't work Both with Spyder/Iphyton

Comment: Did you try from the command line?

Comment: Both Command line and run file

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20330475/1461210

Comment: You are trying to plot a line containing 441000 points, which is a huge number. There's no way you could visually distinguish that many on a normal monitor. Try decimating your `t` and `sweep` vectors (e.g. `plt.plot(t[::100], sweep[::100])`), or reducing the resolution of `t` (e.g. `t = np.linspace(0, t1, 4410)`).

Comment: Sorry didn't find the duplicate via google...  
I know it are large amount of points. but it first start if everything works fine. If the number of points would be a problem than it have also give a problem with the sine wave. That one works even with 20kHz. Also the frequency sweep works when the upper frequency is smaller (to 4000Hz).  
it is somewhere in the combination of the two why i can't plot.
And as last if i can't plot this i cant plot an DFT/ FFT eighter.

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure why the value of `f1` would make any difference, but I can say two things - firstly, decimating the vectors gets rid of the `OverflowError` on my machine, and secondly, even after decimating by 10x, the points are still so dense that they render as a green blob filling the whole plot area. I think you might want to re-think how you are representing the data visually. I'm not sure what you mean by *" if i can't plot this i cant plot an DFT/ FFT eighter"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commend of @ali_m and his link i found a solution.

according to the answer there i need to add `agg.path.chunksize` of 10 000 to 100 000.
because i don't want to do that in the `matplotlibrc` file i had to do that in the script.

According to a discusion on there own [github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/4464) i found the right method doing that.
I have to add `plt.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000` to the script and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me too, on a Windows 7 Professional workstation, Python 3.8.4.

```py
plt rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000
```

My dataset has 67m observations.

Comment: This probably is better left as a comment because it does not answer the question, only affirms that the code works for you in a certain environment.